# Why can't I get the div with a specific class name using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape the [www.airbnb.com](http://www.airbnb.com) site. Specifically, I want to take the URLS with class names "_mm360j" which are inside the divs "_8s3ctt". But my code doesn't find the div "_8s3ctt".

URL = https://www.airbnb.com/s/Madrid--Spain/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=december&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=november&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&query=Madrid%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJgTwKgJcpQg0RaSKMYcHeNsQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click

```
def scrape_page(page_url):
    """Extracts HTML from a webpage"""
    answer = requests.get(page_url)
    content = answer.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features='html.parser')
    return soup

def extract_listing(page_url):
    """Extracts listings from an Airbnb search page"""
    page_soup = scrape_page(page_url)
    listings = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "_8s3ctt"})
    return listings

extract_listing(URL)
```

Comment: did you check what page it returns? maybe the website blocks the request? or redirects to a different page

Comment: no the request isn't blocked. It returns the HTML from the webpage, but neither there it appears the element that i want (div with class name: "_8s3ctt"). @Matiiss

Comment: ok, and it returns the same page you see when going to that link in a browser?

Comment: What has led you to believe that such a non-human-readable class name *isn't* generated on page load to prevent such scraping? When you see such identifiers you can be relatively certain that they are that way for a very good reason... what you're trying to do is very explicitly against Airbnb's Terms of Service, and this is one of many mechanisms they use to prevent such automated scraping.

Comment: maybe it is most common problem: modern pages use JavaScript to add elements but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you should check if it has `API` for developers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

As mentioned in the comments by *Matiis* and *furas* it is a mix of both:

- Website will block your requests by `requests` after a few tries
- Website runs `JavaScript` and request could not render it like a browser can do

#### How to fix?

1. To get the `html` from website use
   [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)
   it will render the website and then response with the "full"
   `page_source`.
2. Instead dealing with the dynamic class names just select the listitems by one of its `attributes`:

   ```
   page_soup.select('[itemprop="itemListElement"]')
   ```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER ON YOUR DEVICE')

def scrape_page(page_url):
    """Extracts HTML from a webpage"""
    driver.get(page_url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract_listing(page_url):
    """Extracts listings from an Airbnb search page"""
    page_soup = scrape_page(page_url)
    listings = page_soup.select('[itemprop="itemListElement"]')
    return listings

items = extract_listing('https://www.airbnb.com/s/Madrid--Spain/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=december&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=november&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&query=Madrid%2C%20Spain&place_id=ChIJgTwKgJcpQg0RaSKMYcHeNsQ&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click')

#process items to get all information you nee, just an example
[{'meta':i.select_one('[itemprop="name"]')['content'],
  'url':i.select_one('[itemprop="url"]')['content']} 
 for i in items]
```

#### Output of example

```
[{'meta': 'Madrid de los Austrias en todo su esplendor',
  'url': 'www.airbnb.de/rooms/46708654?previous_page_section_name=1000&translate_ugc=false'},
 {'meta': 'Habitación con techos altos y ambiente agradable',
  'url': 'www.airbnb.de/rooms/45822566?previous_page_section_name=1000&translate_ugc=false'},
 {'meta': 'Estudio junto a la Plaza Mayor.',
  'url': 'www.airbnb.de/rooms/34997116?previous_page_section_name=1000&translate_ugc=false'},
 {'meta': 'Atocha Suite - Madflats Collection',
  'url': 'www.airbnb.de/rooms/31659379?previous_page_section_name=1000&translate_ugc=false'},
 {'meta': 'Apartamento para temporadas en Plaza de España',
  'url': 'www.airbnb.de/rooms/52639673?previous_page_section_name=1000&translate_ugc=false'},
 {'meta': 'Madrid Centric IV - Madflats Collection',
  'url': 'www.airbnb.de/rooms/35897208?previous_page_section_name=1000&translate_ugc=false'},...]
```